# Why did Beowulf suffer this injury?

Tags: beowulf

In the 2007 film [Beowulf](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0442933/), as he is fighting the dragon near the end, Beowulf..

> Uses his sword to severely injure (or perhaps completely sever?) his left arm that was entangled in the chain that held him to the dragon.

What was the purpose of that act?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beowulf can't reach the dragon's heart with his sword when he's holding on to the chain.

He cuts his own arm off which leaves him hanging by his chain mail. That allows him to stretch further into the cavity, reaching the heart and killing the dragon.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That makes so much sense now you put it like that.  Thank you.  Excellently demonstrative screen-shots BTW.  I now recall seeing each of the events you depict.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - If a thing is worth doing, it's worth doing with crudely drawn red circles...